# How to storyboard localize UITableView header w/ static cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, localization, storyboard

I can't find anything on how to storyboard localize a section's header for a UITableView with static cells.

I tried to take the Table View Section's ID and localize its Header but it's not working. It is never taking my localizations.

```
"eBi-dg-Pbw.header" = "my string";
"eBi-dg-Pbw.text" = "my string";
"eBi-dg-Pbw.title" = "my string";
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

I implemented `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` to localize my sections but I would like to know if there is a way using the localization by storyboard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First option - is wrong names in your storyboard `.strings` file. Correct is:

```
"eBi-dg-Pbw.headerTitle" = "This is the header localisation";
"eBi-dg-Pbw.footerTitle" = "This is the footer localisation";
```

Second option - you need to fill default (dummy) values inside the static section elements in Interface Builder for the both **Header** and **Footer**. At your screenshot filled only the **Header** field with value "my header string" and **Footer** leaved empty

After that - you don't need anymore to implement localisations from the ViewController code